# Scala aggregate function vs. Spark RDD aggregate function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregate-functions, lazy-evaluation

Here are the definitions of the function:

Scala:

```
aggregate[B](z: => B)(seqop: (B, A) => B, combop: (B, B) => B): B
```

Spark RDD:

```
aggregate[B](z: B)(seqop: (B, A) => B, combop: (B, B) => B): B
```

I know that the Scala aggregate function is designed to work on parallel collections and the Spark RDD aggregate function is designed to work on distributed collections.

But, **Why the z parameter in Scala is in lazy format, while in Spark RDD is in eager format?**

Comment: Pretty certain it has to do with Spark's underlying architecture that all transformations are [operated lazily](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-operations).

Comment: It may also be to simplify the calling from **Java**.

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily related to Spark's underlying architecture because other transformations like fold have the same definition in Scala and Spark RDD. So again what is so special in aggregate?

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all this is a **call-by-name** parameter in Scala. This means that they are evaluated every time they are used, which is not the same thing as **lazy**, where it's evaluated only once the first time it's used and all subsequent calls use that result. (https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html)

So spark relies on **distributed** data sets which means computation can be done on multiple nodes. And I think they chose to have the zero element a call-by-value parameter (which what you referred to as 'eager'), to avoid having to recompute it on each and every node where this computation is done.